# Set a default value for list in api.ai

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

For a simple parameter, I can easily set the default value, However I want to mark the parameter as "is list" and then set a default value to it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was much needed feature for me and I have asked this to Dialoglflow support team. But they said for list value, they have no such support right now. So I have created one workaround.

Let's say "location" is list entity. So you need to create another entity i.e. "location_default" ( can be any name convention).

Value of **"location"** entity will always be taken from parameter i.e $Location.

Value of **"location_default"** entity will be #search-context.location where **"search-context"** is the context maintained between different intents and values are passed through this context.

Hence, everytime you have one extra parameter carrying default value. So,  at any step, where **"location"** entity is empty and **"location_default"** is not, just assign it back i.e assign value of **"location_default"** to  **"location"**

Value can be assigned via **"context api"** mentioned in Reference link of Dialogflow Forums.

Hope this solution works for you, as its working like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding the "default" value as context when you send the initial request to api.ai - that might do it (I'm not sure if the user provides the parameter in their request if it will override, but I would expect it to).